# Как кликнув по див запустить iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Как кликнув по див запустить видео в iframe?

Comment: а где ссылка на видео? можно увидеть html

Comment: Ссылка ютубовская

Answer (score 1):

Никак, вы не можете влиять на iframe через javascript на вашем сайте. 
Вы должны использовать [api youtube](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference), что влиять на видео плеер.

Answer (score 0):

Ссылка в диве, при нажатие на див работает видео во фрейме.

```js
document.getElementById('video').onclick = function(){
document.getElementById('frm').src= document.getElementById('video').innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<div id="video">https://www.youtube.com/embed/hv5_p7-Wdqw?rel=0&autoplay=1</div>
<iframe id="frm" width="560" height="315" src="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```